# Запуск команды shell через php

Tags: shell, php, linux

Можно ли запустить с помощью php выполнение Shell команды или запустить крон. Только нужно, чтоб Shell скрипт выполнился от имени юзера, а не от пользователя апача.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для выполнения скрипта от имени юзера, а не от пользователя апача, следует использовать утилиту sudo. Либо же запускать сам php через suexec, в этом случае и php будет работать не от пользователя апача.

Утилита sudo позволяет запускать программы одному пользователю от имени другого. Это делается не бесконтрольно, а в соответствии с указанными разрешениями (прописываются в файле sudoers). В зависимости от настройки в sudoers команду от чужого имени можно запустить либо вообщее без пароля, либо sudo спросит пароль текущего пользователя (т.е. свой, а не того, от кого будет выполняться программа, именно так вызываются все административные утилиты в ubuntu).

Подробнее прочитать про утилиту sudo можно например здесь: [sudo](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=sudo&category=8&russian=0), [sudoers](http://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=sudoers&category=5).

Comment: а получится в php запустить скрипт например user.sh. а в этом файле вставить sudu  cd /home/user/www/public_html; /usr/bin/php cron.php. как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Все таки правильнее будет вызывать sudo user.sh (c нужными параметрами, для их определения надо все таки почитать руководство). А уже из user.sh вызывать cd /home/user/www/public_html; /usr/bin/php cron.php.

Предложенный Вами вариант плох тем, что разрешение на запуск придется давать на весь php.

Я дополнил свой ответ ссылками на руководство по sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Функция exec() или system()

Answer (score 1):

**shell_exec** - выполняет команду в оболочке/shell и возвращает полный вывод в виде строки.

**exec** - выполняет внешнюю программу.

**system** - выполняет внешнюю программу и отображает вывод.

Подробнее: [Функции исполнения системных команд](http://php.su/functions/?cat=exec)

Comment: Ага, толке редко где они разрешены!

Comment: с этим проблем нет..когда свой дедюк:)))

Answer (score 0):

Если по каким-то причинам не удасться воспользоваться sudo, то 
напишите на Си свой простейший враппер к нужным командам , пусть он будет принадлежать руту и установите ему s-бит. Будете при вызове передавать ему команду (скрипт) для выполнения, а также uid и gid от имени кого команду выполнять.

Только он должен аккуратно проверять, кто и с какими параметрами его запускает.